Not connectd to the gnome returned when asking for version ^$ transitionsdj --version ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.^
Ubuntu 24.04 downloaded Transistions DJ using built in app center checked to see if installed by asking for version:
$ transitionsdj --version
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface

.
Also icon that was present in apps is no longer there. Did I not get it all downloaded because of ISP speed
